# Java trim excessive symbols

Tags: java, regex

How can I trim excessive non-numeric, non-alphabetic characters like so:

```
String test = "Hey this is a string with lots of symbols!!!!!@@@@@#####"
```

The output should be:

```
Hey this is a string with lots of symbols!@#
```

What i currently have is this but it has some weird side-effects and its way too bulky:

(first goal was just to trim them, second was to make it a 2-3 liner)

```
    String precheck = message.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", "");

    precheck = precheck.replaceAll("[0-9]+/*\\.*[0-9]*", "");
    precheck = precheck.trim();

    String[] allowed = {
            "!","\"","'","-",">","<","+","_"+"^","@","#","=","/","\\"
    };

    for(char c : precheck.toString().toCharArray())
    {
        boolean contains = false;
        for(String symbol : allowed)
        {
            if(c == symbol.toCharArray()[0]){
                contains = true;
            }
        }

        if(!contains){
            message = message.replace(String.valueOf(c), "");
            message = message.trim();
        }
    }

    for(String symbol : allowed)
    {
        if (message.contains(symbol)){
            int count = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++){
                if (message.charAt(i) == symbol.toCharArray()[0]){
                    count++;
                }
            }

            if(count > 2){
                for(int i = 0;i < (count-2);i++){
                    message = message.replaceFirst(symbol, "");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return message;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use this regex replacement:

```
str = str.replaceAll("([^\\p{L}\\p{N}])\\1+", "$1");
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mA3bQ4/1)

**Explanation:** This regex matches any **non-numeric, non-alphabetic character** and captures it as matched group #1. Regex then matches 1 or more instance of same captured character using `\1+` and replaces them with first part i.e. `$1`.

**PS:** This lookahead regex will also work:

```
str = str.replaceAll("([^\\p{L}\\p{N}])(?=\\1+)", "");
```

Comment: Will mark as answer when SO lets me. Regex is so useful.

Comment: I recommend `[^\p{L}\p{N}]`, because `[^A-Za-z0-9]` unnecessarily excludes valid characters.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have defined a whitelist, I would recommend this approach: Match all allowed symbol characters that are repeated, keep the first one.

```
([!"'><+_^@#=/\\-])\1+
```

in Java

```
String test = "Hey this is a string with lots of symbols!!!!!@@@@@#####";

test = test.replaceAll("([!"'><+_^@#=/\\\\-])\\1+", "$1");
```

result

```
"Hey this is a string with lots of symbols!@#"
```

Comment: added one missing \ preceding 1+